# Is there any way to solve this convex-concave like optimization problem?

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

This is a bit of a non-standard way of asking a question perhaps but I couldnt even think of writing any code about the following optimization problem. I wonder if it could be at all solvable and if it can be I will be very happy to see how.

Given the two sets of probability density functions on real numbers:

$$\mathcal{G}_0=\left\{g_0:\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_0(y)\log(g_0(y)/f_0(y))\mathrm{d}y\leq \epsilon_0\right\} $$ and $$\mathcal{G}_1=\left\{g_1:\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_1(y)\log(g_1(y)/f_1(y))\mathrm{d}y\leq \epsilon_1\right\} $$

I want to determine $g^*_0$ and $g^*_1$ from the two convex-concave type of equations below:

$$g^*_0=\arg\sup_{g_0\in \mathcal{G}_0}\left(\inf_{u\in \mathbb{R}}\ln \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{g_1^*(y)}{g_0^*(y)}\right)^u g_0(y)\mathrm{d}y\right)$$$$g^*_1=\arg\sup_{g_1\in \mathcal{G}_1}\left(\inf_{u\in \mathbb{R}}\ln \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{g_1^*(y)}{g_0^*(y)}\right)^u g_1(y)\mathrm{d}y\right)$$

**Details**:

$f_0$ and $f_1$ are (known) distinct continuous probability density functions, i.e., $f_0\neq f_1$

$\epsilon_0$ and $\epsilon_1$ must be chosen small enough such that $\mathcal{G}_0$ and $\mathcal{G}_1$ are also distinct.

---

I *guess* the problem simplifies **considerably** to finding $g_0^*\in \mathcal{G}_0$ and $g_1^*\in \mathcal{G}_1$ which solves:

$$(g^*_0,g^*_1)=\arg   \sup_{(g_0,g_1)\in \mathcal{G}_0\times \mathcal{G}_1} \inf_{ u\in  [0,1]}\ln \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{g_1(y)}{g_0(y)}\right)^u g_0(y)\mathrm{d}y$$

Thanks in advance for any comment. Any type of numerical solution is welcomed.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask math.stackexchange.com about how to approach the problem first, then ask here about how to implement the approach in Mathematica.

Comment: @Rahul Narain I did it already and i didnt receive any answer. Then I thought perhaps someone here could have an idea in terms of pure application point of view. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Could you explain what  you mean by "pure application point of view"?

Comment: @YvesKlett the theoretical point is: If there is a solution to two equations at the top of the question. If there is a solution, is this solution is unique. Pure application point of view means that we really dont care if there are more solutions or if there exists indeed a solution. What we do is to write a reasonable code to find one solution and then show that, this solution satisfies the equations, indeed.

Comment: First of all the question is how to even represent an arbitrary probability distribution $g$ in a numerics-friendly way. You might divide $\mathbb R$ into a finite number of bins and represent $g$ as the vector of probability mass in each bin, then approximate the integrals by sums over the bins. At least that way, you'd end up with a finite-dimensional optimization problem.

Comment: @RahulNarain yes I was just thinking about it. But is still a bit ill posed. What would be the range of the density? One needs to set it up probably based on the given densities $f_i$. In that case one can also impose smoothness property. I wonder still if this problem could be solved afterwards with a nice convex optimization algorithm?